# javascript history.pushState not working for iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to run a `pushState` and it works fine but when I load the page through an iframe element it refused to work. This is how my code looks like

```
$('a[href]').click(function){
    newHref = $(this).attr('href');
    history.pushState('', '', newHref);
})
```

But it's not working, Please anyone with an idea of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `history.pushState()` changes the url of the iframe source page. To change the main url in the address bar you have to address it to the parent so use this

```
window.parent.history.pushState();
```

Comment: I'm getting Blocked a frame with origin ... from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to keep the function called wrapped in the click event parenthesis...

```
$('a[href]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    newHref = $(this).attr('href');
    history.pushState('', '', newHref);
});
```